# Update external source for data with json after redux has changed

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, couchdb

We have the following scenario:

Our data is in a json store (couchdb).
so we have in our state a json object that corresponds to a particular json document from the store.

eg: article with a list of attributes:

```
{name: 'TV', attributes: {'width': 111, 'height': 123}, ... }
```

now the user through the UI adds a new attribute: weight.

so to update the redux store an action is dispatched and in the reducer the attributes property gets a new item.

since couchdb is a document based storage, we need to send it the complete document.

for that we could, in the action, get the current json add the new attribute, send it to couch and then dispatch the new item again with another action for the state update. this means we actually have 2 times the same code adding the new element.

or we could get the json in the reducer after the update and then update the store.
but this does not actually belong in the reducer

another option might be in componentDidUpdate ... but the component like the reducer are not responsible for updating the data.

so which would be the place to send the new updated json to couch?

Comment: Hi I would decouple the API call from `Redux` and actually do the update only once the API has sent back the updated document which you'd pass to your _action's payload_ and then update your state

Comment: the problem here is that the api expects a full document. this full document is the NEW state in store. so we basically need to change the state and then send the new state to the api

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same problem while starting with Redux and doing some POST requests which updates the state partly.

There are multiple options and i.m.o. none of these options is the right or wrong way to do it. Although, I would suggest sticking with one method to make things more simple and consistent.

The flow we are using boils down to this:

1) The first dispatched action is the instruction to do something. This is also the perfect time to temporarily update the state to reflect the change. This makes the UI feel more responsive.

2) The side effect of the first action can be, for example, a request. We use Redux Sagas to handle this, but there are more options you can choose from.

3) After the side effect has finished, it dispatches a success or failure action. If it succeeded, the success reducer can update the state with the latest values. This is actually important as you cannot guarantee that the change actually happened.

We suffix all of our API actions with a `_SUCCESS` and `_FAILURE` string. It comes with a lot more boilerplate, which is a downside to this method.

This is what it looks like in code:

```js
// action creators
export const editItem = item => ({ type: types.EDIT_ITEM, item });

export const editItemSuccess = payload => ({ type: types.EDIT_ITEM_SUCCESS, payload });

export const editItemFailure = payload => ({ type: types.EDIT_ITEM_FAILURE, payload });

// reducers
export const editItem = state => state.update('edit', datum => datum.merge({
  loading: true,
}));

export const editItemSuccess = (state, { payload }) => state.update('edit', datum => datum.merge({
  loading: false,
  data   : payload,
}));

export const editItemFailure = (state, { payload }) => state.update('edit', datum => datum.merge({
  loading: false,
  error  : payload,
}));
```

Comment: i think this would work if you send to the server only the delta. but in our case we are sending the new state